# 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'insert'

Tags: python, numpy

I want to add one element to a vector which is geting:

```
import time
from numpy import *
from scipy.sparse.linalg import bicgstab,splu
from scipy.sparse import lil_matrix,identity
from scipy.linalg import lu_factor,lu_solve,cho_factor,cho_solve
from matplotlib.pyplot import *

 #N,alfa and beta are introduced

    M = lil_matrix((2*N,2*N), dtype='float64')
    b=zeros(2*N)
    M.setdiag(alfa*ones(2*N),0)
    M.setdiag(beta*ones(2*N-1),1)
    M.setdiag(beta*ones(2*N-1),-1)
    M.setdiag(ones(2*N-2),2)
    M.setdiag(ones(2*N-2),-2)
    M=M.tocsc()

    for i in range(0,2*N):
        b[i]=2*dx*feval(fuente,x[i])/6.0

    A=1.0/(3.0*dx)*M
    u=bicgstab(A,b)
    usol=u[0]
```

And now I want `usol.insert(0,1)  usol=[1,usol[0],usol[1],..]` but I have an error 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'insert'

Comment: `usol = insert(usol, 0, 1)`

Comment: possible duplicate of [python, numpy; How to insert element at the start of an array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20101093/python-numpy-how-to-insert-element-at-the-start-of-an-array)

Comment: Use `usol=np.concatenate(([1], usol))`.  That's all that `np.insert` does.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`insert` is not an attribute of the array. You can use `usol=insert(usol,0,1)` to get the result you want.

Answer (score 10):

In numpy, `insert` is a function, not a method. So you will have to use the following:

```
import numpy as np
#rest of your code
usol=np.insert(usol,0,1)
```

This will create a copy of `usol` with values inserted. Note that insert does not occur in-place.
You can see the docs [here](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.insert.html)